# Chaining Array splice with map?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of variable length that I want to limit to 5 elements before calling a `.map()` on it. However, since `splice(0, 4)` mutates the original array, I can't seem to chain it with the `.map()`. Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
const ids = imageIds.splice(0, 4)
    .map(id => id * -1);
```

So is there anyway to accomplish this in one line or not?

Comment: I think you're looking for [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) rather than `splice`.

Comment: Chaining actually does work with `splice`; is the problem just that you don't want to modify the original array? If so, you want `slice` as stated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could take [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) for a copy with a wanted length.

```js
const
    imageIds = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
    ids = imageIds.slice(0, 5).map(id => id * -1);

console.log(ids);
```